# How to rotate the transform only on the Y?

Tags: unity, c#, rotation

```
private Update()
{
    // Here the transform player should rotate facing the opposite direction.
    // Determine which direction to rotate towards
    Vector3 targetDirection = targetToRotateTo.position - transform.position;

    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Rotate the forward vector towards the target direction by one step
    Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, targetDirection, singleStep, 0.0f);

    // Draw a ray pointing at our target in
    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, newDirection, Color.red);

    // Calculate a rotation a step closer to the target and applies rotation to this object
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDirection);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your object always remains upright (green vector always points up), then this is as simple as zeroing out the y component of your target direction.

```
Vector3 targetDirection = targetToRotateTo.position - transform.position;
targetDirection.y = 0f;

if (targetDirection != Vector3.zero) {
    float singleStep = rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(
                            transform.rotation,
                            Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection),
                            singleStep);
}
```

If your vertical axis might point in an arbitrary direction, then you can use the trick I've explained a few times in past Q&A:

- [Lookrotation of a gameObject in just one axis](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100887/39518)
- [How to rotate CharacterController on a slope](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/168560/39518)
- [Smooth local rotation around one axis, oriented toward a target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/167395/39518)
- [Using Quaternions: What can I do with them?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/133357/39518)