# Rotating with a preferred direction

Tags: unity, rotation, raycasting, quaternion

I do a RayCast to the terrain and then use the RaycastHit.normal to plant flags.

[image]

I would like to have the flags to point up with the normal, but have them all face the same direction. As seen in the image flag 1 points to left of the screen and flag 5 to the right. I understand why, but do not know how to rotate it.

I saw LookRotation (Unity) has an override that takes a forward direction too. I thought it would work with say Vector3.Forward, but if a flag is placed on a wall it points into the wall.

The direction or angle they face can be set by the player.

I have a hard time understanding quaternions, every time I think I do, I get stuck.

Any tips ?

Comment: _"but if a flag is placed on a wall"_ They can be oriented toward the same direction only if this direction is not the same as the surface normal, so if the wall's normal is pointing toward x+, and the user wants them oriented toward x+, you have an issue. What does your game design say when this happens?

Comment: I answer a variation of this question every few months.  [Check the `TurretLookRotation` method in this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/133357/39518) for a way to control the up axis exactly, while guiding the forward direction as close as you can get it given that constraint.